# juju bootstrap fails with connection timed out errors

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, cloud, canonical

This is a follow up question to my [earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536013/juju-bootstrap-fails-with-connection-refused-errors). Back then, juju was hanging trying to connect to the MAAS node. God knows what happened, it went ahead and is now failing with Connection timed out error while trying to download tools from the canonical website. The exact error is -

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to streams.canonical.com port 443: Connection timed out

tools from https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.18.4-trusty-amd64.tgz downloaded: HTTP 000; time 126.330s; size 0 bytes; speed 0.000 bytes/s 

2014-10-16 23:32:08  ERROR juju.provider.common bootstrap.go:123 bootstrap failed: rc: 1
```

The link from where juju is trying to download stuff is a perfectly valid one.

I saw people having similar problems in connecting to `https://streams.canonical.com`  but there the problem was juju was unable to resolve the hostname but I don't think thats the case with our problem

Any hints are welcome.

**EDIT**: While juju hangs trying to connect to canonical before giving up, I ran `juju -status` from another terminal. It shows this error

`ERROR state/api: websocket.Dial wss://slot13.maas:17070/: dial tcp 10.10.10.102:17070: connection refused`

`10.10.10.102` is the private IP of our remote node. On one terminal juju says its trying download tools to deploy the node and on the other node, it says that remote node is refusing connection. Quite paradoxical!

Answer (score 2):

If, in maas, 10.10.10.102 is set as your gateway, this would be expected behavior.  At least it would be by me, having been bitten by this king of thing. I renamed the machine I was use for juju bootstrap to jujuBS, so try this, which bring everything you need local to the maas server:

```
mkdir ~./.juju/sync-tools
juju sync-tools –e maas –destination=”~/.juju/sync-tools”
juju bootstrap –e maas –-upload-tools=true –-metadata-source=”.juju/sync-tools” -–to jujuBS.local
mkdir –p ~/.juju/charms/trusty
juju charm get juju-gui .juju/charms/trusty
juju deploy –repository=”~/.juju/charms” local:juju-gui
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error on my environment and I've resolved that run the following command:

```
$: juju bootstrap -e maas --to JujuGui.maas  --upload-tools --debug
```

below the result of the debug:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14696174/

after that I installed juju-gui

```
$: juju status -e maas
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.25.3.1
    dns-name: JujuGui.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-0672fb10-c53d-11e5-a26c-525400c4a170/
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1024M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
services: {}

$: juju deploy juju-gui --to 0
```

running this command obtain this error

```
ERROR cannot retrieve charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-44": cannot get archive: Get https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v4/trusty/juju-gui-44/archive: dial tcp 162.213.33.122:443: connection refused
```

why?